# MySQL: Summarize two statements

Tags: mysql

If it is possible - how can I put those two selections together, so I only have to send one query to the server instead of two (as I'm doing it right now).

As the where part defines exactly one result and all the other field are grouped in a string, the result has only one row.

The grouped strings will be processed in php as array. So I have a result with exact one image (id and name) and five array (the first four arrays belongs together as they define together spots in the image; the fifth array has names of the child images)

```
SELECT 
    main.id, 
    main.name,  
    group_concat(details.id), 
    group_concat(details.top), 
    group_concat(details.left), 
    group_concat(details.description)
FROM images_main main 
LEFT JOIN images_details details ON main.name = details.name 
WHERE main.name = 'specific_name' 
GROUP BY main.name 


SELECT 
    main.id, 
    main.name,
    group_concat(child.name)
FROM images_main main 
LEFT JOIN images_main child ON main.id = child.parent_id
WHERE main.name = 'specific_name' 
GROUP BY main.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the aggregation in subqueries, and then combine them together using `left outer join`.  Start with the `main` table, to be sure you don't lose any rows, in case one of the subqueries returns no rows:

```
select id.*, child.childs
from images_main main left outer join
     (SELECT details.name, group_concat(details.id) as ids, group_concat(details.top) as tops,
             group_concat(details.left) as lefts, group_concat(details.description) as descriptions
      FROM images_details details 
      WHERE details.name = 'specific_name' 
      GROUP BY details.name
     ) id
     on main.name = id.name left outer join
     (SELECT main.id, group_concat(child.name) as childs
      FROM images_main main join
           images_main child
           ON main.id = child.parent_id
      WHERE main.name = 'specific_name' 
      GROUP BY main.name
    ) child
    on main.id = child.id
WHERE main.name = 'specific_name' ;
```

Comment: Wow, that is quite impressive for me as I didn't use complex sql-queries so far. And this is really faster, than doing a while-loop in the php-script and alsway sending a simple select-query?

Comment: @user3142695 . . . Generally doing the processing in the database is faster than doing processing in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to merge the results into one resultset.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't get that because both parts have different (amount) fields...

Comment: You can add fixed values to match the number of fields, if the solution generally suits your needs.